# Pegar o $index de um ng-repeat que contenha um ng-controller no $scope em AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat, ng-controller

Tenho uma aplicação que utiliza um `ng-repeat` para listar informações. Assim:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="listaCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in lista" ng-controller="itemCtrl">
        <pre>{{item}}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

Estou utilizando [este exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20024156/how-to-watch-changes-on-models-created-by-ng-repeat) para trabalhar sobre cada item da lista, e preciso saber o index que esse `ng-repeat` contém dentro do meu `itemCtrl`.

Existe algum método para pegar o $index do `ng-repeat` dentro do meu controller?

Comment: Pegar o `index` quando?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Utilize a constante `$index` normalmente, ela é referenciada no escopo *parent*. O sample abaixo demonstra este comportamento:

```js
function listCtrl($scope) {
  
  $scope.items = [{name:'a'},{name:'b'},{name:'c'}];
  
}

function itemCtrl($scope) {
  
  console.log('Index atual:' + $scope.$index);
  
}
```

```html
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="listCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="i in items" ng-controller="itemCtrl">
        <pre>{{$index}} - {{i}}</pre>
      </div>      
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

O resultado no console é o seguinte:

```
Index atual:0
Index atual:1
Index atual:2
```

Comment: valeu parceiro, já tava imaginando um monte de abobrinha que eu ia ter que jogar isso como um input dentro do bloco do controller, e bla bla bla rs..

Comment: @LeandroLUK Sempre um prazer ajudar - o pessoa do Angular fez um bom trabalho, o número de gambiarras realmente necessário é mínimo. ;)

Comment: sem sombra de dúvidas! to doido pra sair o Angular2 e começa a estudar ele direitinho (já tem na verdade mas ainda ta em beta)